# How to get the four graphs generated from the regression analysis in R?

Tags: r, plot, graph, lm, anova

How to get the four graphs generated (one separated from the other/one at a time) from the regression analysis not by using the console / prompt (`Hit <Return> to see next plot:`)?

```
if(!require("truncnorm")) install.packages("truncnorm") ; library(truncnorm)


FACTORA <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
FACTORB <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
FACTORC <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
FACTORD <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
FACTORE <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)

planDOE <- data.frame(FACTORA, 
                  FACTORB, 
                  FACTORC, 
                  FACTORD, 
                  FACTORE, 
                  rtruncnorm(n=32, a=0, mean=61.16, sd=31.32))

rg <- lm(planDOE)
plot(rg)
```

I tried the following ways and did not succeed (either using true or false in the ask argument commands `ask`).

```
plot(rg)
par(ask=TRUE)
```

#

```
par(ask=FALSE)
plot(rg)
```

#

```
plot(rg, ask = FALSE)
```

#

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(rg)
# In one image it can put together the graphic information.
```

#

```
png('test2.png', units="in", width=13, height=7, res=300)
plot(rg)
dev.off()
```

In this last way, I realize that it is possible to obtain the graph separately, but only saves the graph of residuals.

The answer:

```
plot(rg, which = 1)
plot(rg, which = 2)
#...
```

Comment: See `?plot.lm`. You can do `plot(rg, ask = FALSE)`.

Comment: @Marius In this way `plot (rg, ask = FALSE)` continues to appear at the prompt.

Comment: @bbiasi, my guess is you did not clear your `par(ask=TRUE)` before you tried `plot(rg, ask=FALSE)`. When you do `par(ask=TRUE)`, it will always ask whenever a new figure is drawn; try `par(ask=TRUE);plot(1);plot(2);` to see that it always asks, and this behavior has nothing to do with your question involving `plot.lm`. Reading help pages before you come to StackOverflow might have helped here; in this case: [`?par`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html)  (search for `"ask"`) and [`?plot.lm`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/plot.lm.html).

Comment: @r2evans https://i.imgur.com/OIy7xqg.png
Can u help me? How 'did not clear'?

Comment: If you start in a fresh "R" session, `par("ask")` will return `FALSE`, indicating its default. When I said *"did not clear"*, I was suggesting (vaguely) that you were not in the default state, instead still under `par(ask=TRUE)`. The option remains until you close the graphic device which may be easier in R than in RStudio's interface (which generally always has the graphic device directly or indirectly available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually see this if you had done `?plot.lm`

```
mod <- lm(1:10 ~ rnorm(10))
```

Now you can plot each of the plots separately specifying the `which` argument in `plot.lm`. As in,

```
png('plot_1.png', units="in", width=13, height=7, res=300)
 plot(mod, which = 1)
dev.off()

png('plot_2.png', units="in", width=13, height=7, res=300)
 plot(mod, which = 2)
dev.off()

plot(mod, which = 3)
plot(mod, which = 5)
```

These will plot the figure you'd normally get if you use `plot(mod)`.

Naturally, you can save after each plot, or only the plots you prefer.

*NOTE*: I didn't use `which = 4`.

Comment: Thank you! @Suren

Comment: Could you tell me how I can save it with an object?
`> plot1 <- plot(rg, which = 1)
> plot1
NULL`

Comment: I don't think you can save a `plot` like that in base R. A package like `ggplot2` is useful if you want to something like that.

Comment: By the way, you don't have to give the anwer in your question. You should hit the tick mark next to the anwer sloved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

set  par(mfrow = params). using mtcars, here's an example. You can save the plot as a .png file afterwards

```
rg <- lm(mpg~cyl + wt, data = mtcars)

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(rg)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Sebastian, in one image it actually manages to gather the graphical information.
https://i.imgur.com/7Sbdyj1.png

But do you know how to get each image separately?